# consultar rango de fechas dentro de un join en SQL

Tags: jquery, base-de-datos, datatables, join

nesecito filtrar mi consulta por un dia en especifico y junto con otros rangos dentro de un join, tengo este query, ojala alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias.

```
select r.application as "Fecha transacción", r.id as "Id transacción",
r.type_movement as "Tipo transacción",
p.payment_method_id as "Via de acceso",
(cast(p.amount as double precision) + p.extra_amount) as "Monto total", p.extra_amount as "Comisión",
p.payment_id as "Número de autorización", p.amount as "Monto Deposito",
u.name as "Nombre", u.phone as "Telefóno", u.email as "Mail"
from records as r
inner join payments as p on p.payment_id = r.reference
left join users as u on u.id = r.user_id
order by r.application;
```

Comment: select r.application as "Fecha transacción", r.id as "Id transacción",
r.type_movement as "Tipo transacción",
p.payment_method_id as "Via de acceso",
(cast(p.amount as double precision) + p.extra_amount) as "Monto total", p.extra_amount as "Comisión",
p.payment_id as "Número de autorización", p.amount as "Monto Deposito",
u.name as "Nombre", u.phone as "Telefóno", u.email as "Mail"
from records as r
inner join payments as p on p.payment_id = r.reference
left join users as u on u.id = r.user_id
order by r.application;

Comment: Me imagino que te refieres a filtrar los datos por el campo `application`?

Answer (score 0):

Si la fecha es "r.application" y esta en formato fecha. Entonces podes agregar lo siguiente:

```
WHERE r.application="2018-06-01"
```

Si no esta en ese formato por favor mostranos un ejemplo de como esta cargado ese registro para que podamos decirte mejor que agregar.

Proba tambien agregando la funcion date(). O sea te quedaria asi:

```
WHERE date(r.application)="2018-06-01"
```

Saludos!

Comment: HOLA, con  WHERE r.application="2018-06-01"  me sale este error:                                                                    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: select WHERE r.application='2018:06:02' as "Fecha transacció...
                                                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 41

Comment: y con este   WHERE date(r.application)="2018-06-01"   me sale:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: select WHERE date(r.application='2018:06:02') as "Fecha tran...
                                                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 47

Comment: Que tal Issra?. Como dije, nose bien como es el formato del campo application. Entendí a tu pregunta que la fecha estaba en ese campo y deduje que estaba en formato date. Por favor pasame un ejemplo de como esta así te puedo ayudar bien y no estamos probando cosas que no nos lleven a ningún lado. Si querés, podes hacer un "SELECT * FROM records LIMIT 1" para traer una fila de ejemplo. Espero tu respuesta, Saludos!